# Simultaneous rotation in Matrix

Tags: c, opengl

Can anyone help me (again) please? I have a Matrix like this:

```
1.0  0.0  0.0  2.5
0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

How can I rotate it 20° in X axis, -128° in Y axis and 72.1° in Z axis simultaneously?

thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want rotate … in X axis, … in Y axis and … in Z axis simultaneously

You can't. What you ask for is mathematically undefined. There are 6 permutations of the order in which the elementary rotations could be combined…

- X Y Z
- X Z Y
- Y X Z
- Y Z X
- Z X Y
- Z Y X

and each of them has a different result. Rotations don't work the way you think. Mathematically rotations in 3 dimensional space form a special unitary group of degree 2, also written as SU(2). Each rotation in SU(2) is unique but can be constructed by combining an infinite number of other rotations in SU(2).

In your particular case there's no particular solution to the problem. The best thing you can do is choose a particular execution order and apply the rotations one after another onto your existing coordinate system, by forming the corresponding rotation matrix and multiplying onto the matrix representing the previous coordinate system/transformation step.